# How to display a Vue/Nuxt array with a maximum of 10 items and a button to pull in more items?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm creating a page that lists 10 items of data from an array using javascript/vue/nuxt, which consists of an javascript array with props. The page is a list of websites with some information. At the moment, the page displays the data fine, but i'm wondering is there a way to display a maximum of 10 items per page and pull all the data from a single file instead of directly writing it onto the page?

I'd like the page to display 10 items from the array and when someone clicks a button, it shows the next 10 items and so forth. I'd also need a second button that allows you to go back to the previous 10 lists. What's the best way to go about this?

Website List Page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="websites-container">
      <website
        logo="/images/logos/example.jpg"
        link="hwww.example.com"
        name="Website Name"
        description="This is one website"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The array 'website' code:

```
<template>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img :src="logo" :href="link" target="_blank">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <h3 v-text="name" />
      <a v-show="info" class="info" :href="infolink" v-text="info" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p v-show="description" class="description" v-text="description" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    logo: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    link: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    info: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    infolink: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: So it only shows 10 items at a time (ie pagination) or is it more like an ever growing list (ie infinite scroll)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to paginate an array, I'd recommend creating a computed property that uses `Array.prototype.slice()`

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  page: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  list: [{
    logo: "/images/logos/example.jpg",
    link: "https://www.example.com",
    name: "Website Name",
    description: "This is one website"
  }, {
    // etc
  }]
}),
computed: {
  currentPage () {
    return this.list.slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, this.page * this.pageSize)
  },
  totalPages () {
    return Math.ceil(this.list.length / this.pageSize)
  }
},
methods: {
  nextPage () {
    this.page = Math.min(page + 1, totalPages)
  },
  prevPage () {
    this.page = Math.max(page - 1, 1)
  }
}
```

Then all you have to do is have your *next* and *previous* buttons increment or decrement `page`

```html
<div class="websites-container">
  <website
    v-for="website in list"
    :key="website.link"
    :logo="website.logo"
    :link="website.link"
    :name="website.name"
    :description="website.description"
  />
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" @click="nextPage">Next</button>
  <button type="button" @click="prevPage">Previous</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. Modified it to suit what I needed... Totally worked!